# Why does length come up as undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="aa">
  <input type='radio' id="1" name='choices' value='1'/>
  <input type='radio' id ="2" name='choices' value='2'/>

  <input type='radio' id="3" name='choices1' value='3'/>
  <input type='radio' id="4" name='choices1' value='4'/>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".aa :radio").change(function() {

  var names = {};
  $('.aa :radio').each(function() { // find unique names
    names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
  });
  var count = 0;
  $.each(names, function() { // then count them
    count++;
  });
  alert ("count " + count +  " length " + names.length); //names length comes up as undefined why?
}).change();
```

Comment: Javascript objects do not have a length property:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-associative-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `names` is an `object` not an `array`. In your example, count would be the length of the keys in the object names.

To get the length of the keys:

```
var count = 0;
for(var i in names) {
  count++;
} 
count; // length
```

Or modern browsers `Object.keys(names).length`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript objects do not have a length property. Only array's do.

If you want to know how many keys are in your object, you'll have to loop through it. Check out the answer to this question:

[Length of a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-associative-array)